# I added a category named "Home". Can i change the link in the original homepage?

Tags: category, redirect, home

For example:
The ***category*** link is `www.mypage.com/index.php/home`
and the ***homepage*** is `www.mypage.com/index.php`.

What i want is: When i click on the category button `Home`. I want to be redirected to the home page.

how can i fix this?

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding new category for homepage, you should add just menu link for the home page. See below link of previous stackexchange question for more details on how to do that.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902873/add-homepage-link-to-magento-menu-bar

Comment: thank you,

I will try it tonight!

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but it's not working. Can you help me?

Comment: @Shabbir, maybe you could copy the answer here. So it easier to reference when other search the same thing! Thanks!

Comment: @ivan-djakie

First turn on Developer mode and find out path to your page/html/topmenu.phtml file  
After getting location, edit topment.phtml file and locate <ul> tag and below that add  
`<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?></a>
</li>`